# Testing Custom Hook and useEffect Not Firing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I am testing a small custom hook and I can't get the `useEffect` inside of it to fire. I have the hook in a mounted component and have tested other custom hooks that do not have a `useEffect` with this method successfully.
The ref gets set to `false` as expected (and breaks as expected when set to `true`), but it never updates to `true` when `useEffect` should have ran. The code works when ran outside of a test.

My hook:

```
export default function useIsComponentMounted() {
    const isMountedRef = useRef(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        isMountedRef.current = true;
        return function cleanup() {
            isMountedRef.current = false;
        };
    }, []);
    return isMountedRef.current;
}
```

My method of mounting:

```
function TestHook(props) {
    const { callback } = props;
    callback();
    return <div />;
}

export const testHook = callback => mount(<TestHook callback={callback} />);
```

My Test:

```
describe('useIsComponentMounted', () => {
    it('should keep track of if a component is mounted', () => {
        let expected = true;
        let mounted;
        const component = testHook(() => {
            mounted = useIsComponentMounted();
        });
        expect(mounted).toBe(expected);
        component.unmount();
        expected = false;
        expect(mounted).toBe(expected);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I *think* is happening:

`useEffect` takes place after render, so when you expect `mounted` to be true, `useEffect` has not yet run. Updating a ref does not trigger a re-render, so your component never updates.

The way I got this to work is by forcing an update, by calling `component.setProps()` before each expectation:

```
    it('should keep track of if a component is mounted', () => {
        let mounted;
        const component = testHook(() => {
            mounted = useIsComponentMounted();
        });
        component.setProps(); // Feels a bit hacky, but it forces a re-render
        expect(mounted).toBe(true);
        component.unmount();
        component.setProps(); // This apparently even works after unmount!
        expect(mounted).toBe(false);
    });
```

This diagram is helpful to show when render, DOM updates, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, and paints happen: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/donavon/hook-flow/master/hook-flow.png

Comment: This solved it, thanks. I fully expected `useEffect` to run on mount not thinking that there has not been a render to run after yet. That is not the case.